# Multiple attributes condition in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I'd like to check if a "couple" of attributes is in a the result of another request.
I tried the following query but the syntax isn't good.

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table1
WHERE (Col_01, Col_02) IN
(
    SELECT Col_01, Col_02
    FROM Table2
)
```

Is-it possible to do something like that in T-SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t2.Col_01 = t1.Col_01 AND
          t2.Col_02 = t1.Col_02
)
```

You initial attempt was a good one though - some database systems do allow us to use rowset constructors to create arbitrary tuples, and the syntax is quite similar to what you showed, but they're not supported in T-SQL in this part of the syntax, so you have to go this slightly more verbose route.